# Yii rules urlManager

Tags: yii, rules

My URL Rule is as below :

```
'product-<typeproduct:.{1,255}>-prd-<positionIds:[\d\-]+>.html' => 'site/products/bycate',
```

I want to get `positionIds` in Array variable.
So is it possible to send `positionIds` in Array as below ? :

```
'product-<typeproduct:.{1,255}>-prd-<positionIds:array[\d\-]+>.html' => 'site/products/bycate',
```

Comment: Excuse me, but your question doesn't make much sense - try to clarify it a bit more so we can try to help you. For example, both of your urlManagerRules are the same, there's no difference between them.

Comment: ahh I think the editor used in the site has deleted characters that I put.

OK, so my rule is:

'product-<prdname:.{1,255}>-product-<producId:\d+>.html' => 'site/products/bycate',


i want the vriable sent in this rule to be array type so that in my php action when i get (producId) i get producId in array type

Comment: Changed Formatting, Grammer & Spellings.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to get it as array so url would be something like this:

```
'/product-2-prd-222,223,224.html'
```

Where `222,223,224` are positionId's  that you want to obtain in array. 
As of I know, this cannot be done without creating urlRule class which would look something like this:

```
class ProductsUrlRule extends UrlRule
{

  public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
  {
     if (preg_match("/product-([0-9]+)-prd-([0-9,]+).html/",$request,$vars)===3) {

           $typeProduct = $var[1];
           $productIds = explode(',',$var[2]);

           return [
               'controller/action', 
               'typeproduct'=> $typeProduct, 
               'positionIds'=>$productIds
           ];
     }
  }
}
```

this will parse example url that I showed you above to something like this:

```
'?r=controller/action&typeproduct=2&positionIds[]=222&positionIds[]=223&positionIds[]=224'
```

Ofcourse you need to replace `controller/action` with your controller/action pair and later to validate fields.

Comment: if i use htacces ?

Comment: My htaccess : 
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
<filesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A259200
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A7200
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
Satisfy any
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteRule ^jobs-([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)-pos-([0-9]+)\.html$ offres.html?id[]=$2 [L]